# Blender 2.5 Python animated world texture setup

Tags: python, blender, blender-2.50, bpython

I need to set up an animated (i.e. from video file) world texture in blender 2.58 using python.
I make a texture like this:

```
import bpy
# create new clouds texture
bpy.ops.texture.new()
wtex = bpy.data.textures[-1]
# set World texture
wrld = bpy.data.worlds['World']
slot = wrld.texture_slots.add()
slot.texture = wtex
slot.use_map_horizon = True
```

This creates a new *CloudsTexture* and binds it to slot. How can I make an *ImageTexture* and set it up to have a video as a source? Or, how can I specify the type of a new texture made by bpy.ops.texture.new()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For data addition/removal, its best not to use operators, we have api functions from bpy.data for this.

```
import bpy
# create new clouds texture
wtex = bpy.data.textures.new(name="MyTexture", type='IMAGE')
# set World texture
wrld = bpy.context.scene.world
if wrld:
    slot = wrld.texture_slots.add()
    slot.texture = wtex
    slot.use_map_horizon = True
```

Tested with blender 2.58a