# Blender 2.5 Python video texture info

Tags: python, video, textures, blender, blender-2.50

I load an animated texture in Blender 2.58 using python like this (see [this question earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6681039/blender-2-5-python-animated-world-texture-setup)):

```
#setup world
wtex = bpy.data.textures.new(name="WorldTexture", type='IMAGE')
# set World texture
wrld = bpy.context.scene.world
if wrld:
    slot = wrld.texture_slots.add()
    slot.texture = wtex
    slot.use_map_horizon = True
    img=bpy.data.images.load(filepath='\\vtex.avi')
    if img:
      slot.texture.image=img
```

How can I get the number of frames in the video (img)? Blender obviously does it when loading a texture from GUI, but I didn't find a way to make it from Python.

Comment: I realized blender was installed on a computer at the office, so I had a shot, but unfortunatly couldn't find anything. If you load it as a texture instead there is a `animFrames` property, but it was always `100` on the files I tested :(

Comment: Thanks for noticing, that might help. I'll check it tomorrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `img.frame_duration`; It gives the total number of frames in the video.

Comment: can you explain a little more

Comment: "How can I get the number of frames in the video?" - 
img.frame_duration gives the total number of frames in the video.
Did I misunderstood the question?